# Close Windows CMD console on play start

Tags: batch-file, playframework-1.x

'm trying to start my play app via "play start" command in windows but the CMD console remains open after server started. Also system.err still redirected to this console.
And if I close this windows the application's java process also will be closed.

Framework version: 1.2.4/1.2.5.3
Platform you're using: Windows 2003, 7 (X86, X64)

Reproduction steps:
1) Create Play! app
2) Start it via bat file

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7
cd /d "%dp~0%TestApp"
call "%dp~0%../play-1.2.4/play" start
```

[image: play start cmd window]

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
start "" "%dp~0%../play-1.2.4/play" start
```

However, it looks like `play` is a console application and thus will just create a new window anyway.

Comment: The same, if I close this console window, the play server stops working.

Comment: There's two consoles here: One for your batch file and another for `play`. If you can somehow coerce `play` to use `javaw` instead of `java` you won't get one.

Comment: Update Pyton's script to use javaw is probably a solution, but I don't understand how it supposed to work.

Comment: Windows distinguishes between two kinds of applications (well, more, but not important right now): Console and GUI applications. Console applications inherit their parent's console window by default and `cmd` waits while they are executing. GUI applications by default have no console and `cmd` doesn't wait for them to exit.